# Validation Expression - C#

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to create a validation expression for a table name in the format of:

> Name_TableName_YYYYMMDD

right now I have something like this:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9][^_]+[a-zA-Z0-9][^_]+\d{8}
```

Number at the end can read 8 digits.

Comment: Could you elaborate more what table name, for a user?

Comment: You might want to use a regex generator/validator tool. There are so many of them online. My tool of choice is `regex hero`. Online and very good.

Comment: do you have any special requirements on the date at the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this (very basic) expression

```
[a-zA-Z]+_[a-zA-Z]+_[0-9]{4}(0[1-9]|1[0-2])(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])
```

Link to [a test](https://regex101.com/r/vS3fC8/66)